# VBA: Run-time error 3220 “Supplied provider is different from the one already in use”

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I get the error message

```
Run-time error 3220 "Supplied provider is different from the one already in use"
```

When I try to run the following command in a file that I have received

```
datConnection.Open (Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\Excel files Test\Macros\example 1.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1')
```

Any idea why I get the error and how I can change it to make it work?

I don't know if it is relevant but I have

```
Windows 7 x64
Excel 2013
```

Comment: check [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) and change your connection string according to information you find there.

Comment: I've been to that page before, but there are many connection strings there. I don't understand which of them I should change to or why.

Comment: choose one which refers to file you take data from: '.xlsx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the first example on the [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) page that KazJaw linked to:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\Excel files Test\Macros\example 1.xlsx"";
Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
```

The version you were using before only works for the older .xls format. The data source contains spaces so needs to be surrounded by double quotes. Those double quotes need to be escaped by doubling them up